# how to display loading image on radio button click event asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to asp.net can someone tell,
How to display a loading image on radio button clicked event?
below are my code:-

```
<fieldset class="feildset">
          <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Output" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Larger"></asp:Label><br />
          <div class="radioBtn">
                <asp:RadioButton CssClass="checkmark" ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text="1" OnCheckedChanged="Group1" AutoPostBack="True" GroupName="Ktek"  />
                <br />
                <asp:RadioButton CssClass="checkmark" ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text="2" OnCheckedChanged="Group1" AutoPostBack="True" GroupName="Ktek"/>
                <br />
                <asp:RadioButton CssClass="checkmark"  ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" Text="3" OnCheckedChanged="Group1" AutoPostBack="True" GroupName="Ktek" />
                <br />
                <asp:RadioButton CssClass="checkmark" ID="RadioButton4" runat="server" Text="4" OnCheckedChanged="Group1" AutoPostBack="True" GroupName="Ktek" />
                <br />
                <asp:RadioButton CssClass="checkmark" ID="RadioButton5" runat="server" Text="5" OnCheckedChanged="Group1" AutoPostBack="True" GroupName="Ktek" />
                <br />
            </div>
</fieldset>
```

image details:-

```
<div class="loading" style="margin-top: 100px; margin-left: 330px; display: none">
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Loading_icon.gif?20151024034921" />
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could/should consider a RadioButton list. However, to show a spinner while you wait for the server side code, you can add a client side click event like this:

```
            <asp:RadioButton CssClass="checkmark" ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" 
                Text="1" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged" 
                AutoPostBack="true"
                onclick="myspin()"
                 GroupName="Ktek"  />
```

you do above for each button you have.

then, your markup looks like this:

```
        <div id="mydiv" class="loading" 
            style="margin-top: 100px; margin-left: 330px; display: none">
            <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Loading_icon.gif?20151024034921" />
        </div>

        <script>
            function myspin() {
                $('#mydiv').show()
            }
        </script>
```

Now, I assume you have jQuery for above.

So, when you click a button, the "spinner" will show, and when the page round trip (browser page returns from server), then the spinner will automatic re-hide.

As I pointed out, a Radio button list would be somewhat less code, since a RadioButtonList has ONE event, and thus you would not need the groupid, nor have to attached a click event (client side), nor setup a server side click for each option selected.

So, you would wind up with this:

So, above using a Radio button list, we have this markup:

```
      <div style="float:left">
          <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RBList" runat="server"
              OnSelectedIndexChanged="RBList_SelectedIndexChanged"
              RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
              CssClass="rMyChoice"
              AutoPostBack="true"
              onclick="myspin()"
              >
              <asp:ListItem>One</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>Two</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>Three</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>Four</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>Five</asp:ListItem>
          </asp:RadioButtonList>
       </div>
            <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server"
                style="float:left;margin-left:30px">
            </asp:Label>

        <div id="mydiv" style="clear:both; display: none">
            <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Loading_icon.gif?20151024034921" />
        </div>

        <script>
            function myspin() {
                $('#mydiv').show()
            }
        </script>
```

And code behind is this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void RBList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sbuf =
        $"Index choice {RBList.SelectedIndex.ToString()} <br/>" +
        $"Text choice = {RBList.Text}";
    lblMsg.Text= sbuf ;
    // fake 2 seconds worth of processing
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

And the result is now this:

[image]

And even better, is the Radio Button list can accept a data source.

Regardless of what choice, adding a simple client side click event to un-hide the "spinner" works well, and after the server side code is done, then the client side spinner will re-hide automatic for you anyway.